# Looking to hire someone to search Seforim (online or not) for specific Torah thoughts

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

I have several Torah thoughts that may potentially be novel, and I am searching to see what other commentators have written on these subjects and whether some or all of these thoughts were introduced previously by other commentators.

Websites such as [**www.Otzar.org**](http://otzar.org) and [**www.Hebrewbooks.org**](http://hebrewbooks.org) are very helpful to do searches within Seforim, given their huge databases and the ability to do "keyword searches". However, since I am not the most proficient when it comes to both the ordinary non-technical delving into Seforim, and am neither a very savvy user of "online search" tools, I was hoping I could find someone whom I could retain and pay to do some extensive searching of several hours.

In other words, I would provide all the relevant details on the Chiddushim/P'shatim regarding which we are searching, and hopefully a Talmid Chochom who is also technically-proficient could then research using these aforementioned databases, or better yet, he may also have access to other proprietary and exclusive databases, etc.

Does anyone know whom I could contact or where I could go to obtain such help?

Comment: You could try the coffee room of [Yeshiva World News](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom), right profile of people knowledgeable in tech and Torah - just like here of course. I would highly recommend running a test where you know the answers before hiring someone

Comment: Unless (or even despite that) you have innumerable novel ideas you can simply post them here at MY and ask if users know of earlier progenitors.

Comment: A number of *kolelim* pay people to learn. You might want to try offering to fund the yeshiva or organization that funds these people.

Comment: @user13763 I may be interested.  If you don't mind posting your email address here, I will contact you.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore thank you very much. My email address is chairman@mviewproducts.com